# Worklight audio play, and control

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, html5-audio

Worklight 6.1

I have a worklight application that will be deployed to both Android, and iOS devices.  A feature of the application is to play & control fixed audio files stored within the application. The files are in .wav format, but can be converted to mp3 if necessary (mpeg).  Using the audio tag the audio play & control works fine in Android emulators (Chrome), but when the app is deployed to an Android device (ex: Nexus-7 4.1.2) the audio tag is not working.

I've read that there are issues with Android devices 4.X playing audio using the audio tag.  Can someone please suggest the best approach to playing, and controlling audio  (start, stop, pause, reset to beginning) that will work across both Android, and iOS devices.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From past experience, [Cordova's Media API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media) worked for me in both iOS and Android 4.
You can try that.

Comment: Thank You.  Making progress on the implementation using the link you provided.